# What is an alternative for zcache?

Tags: linux-kernel, swap, cache, zram

I want to use a high-speed swap device or [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) as ["page cache"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), so that page data can be dropped automatically when the system is out of memory.

Apparently, [`zcache`](https://lwn.net/Articles/397574/) has been discontinued. Is there an available alternative? If yes, which one?

`bcache` doesn't seem to drop data when there's no memory available.

Comment: How do you define "page cache"? Do you mean memory management scheme, a.k.a. swap? If so, `bcache` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski [In computing, a page cache, sometimes also called disk cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)

Comment: You English is difficult to understand, and you seem to mix unrelated concepts, so the noise level in your question is rather high. That's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: You ask about how to use swap device as "page cache". You control which swap devices the kernel should use (and their priorities) with `swapon` and `swapoff` commands. It doesn't matter what is the actual storage for the device, whether it is a zram, disk partition, or bcache.

Comment: I'm sorry for my express way,in fact I trying find a alternative for `zcache` @AdamRyczkowski thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed `zcache` appears to have been discontinued, as it was [removed from kernel 3.11](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=96256460487387d28b8398033928e06eb9e428f7) for being effectively obsolete. The commit message of zcache removal reads

> staging: zcache: delete it
>
> zcache is obsolete and not used anymore, Bob Liu has rewritten it and
>   is submitting it for inclusion through the main -mm tree, as it should
>   have been done in the first place...

It appears that [Bob Liu's submission](https://lwn.net/Articles/562254/) never got into mainline.

Now, the way I understand it, the page cache *is* automatically "dropped" (cleared) in an out-of-memory scenario. `zcache` actually implemented compression so it could maintain *more* filesystem pages (also known as "vfs cache" or "inode/dentry cache") before being dropped.

The Linux kernel has [zswap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zswap) today that implements compressed disk-based swapping, but doesn't compress filesystem pages.

I am not aware of a current day alternative for zcache.

Perhaps as a workaround, if you are concerned with performance degradation due to filesystem pages being freed, consider tuning [`vm.vfs_cache_pressure`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) [as instructed here](https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/tales-from-responsivenessland-why-linux-feels-slow-and-how-to-fix-that).

For normal workloads it's safe to just settle with `zswap`.

Additional reading:

1. [zram vs zswap vs zcache Ultimate guide: when to use which one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471912/zram-vs-zswap-vs-zcache-ultimate-guide-when-to-use-which-one)
2. [Zswap, Zram, Zcache desktop usage scenarios](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99580/zswap-zram-zcache-desktop-usage-scenarios)
3. [zswap (Arch Linux Wiki)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zswap)
4. [Cleancache and Frontswap (LWN)](https://lwn.net/Articles/386090/)
5. [The Case for Compressed Caching in Virtual Memory Systems](https://yanniss.github.io/compression.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

NVMe?    -hardware fix
BTRFS Compression?  -software fix

Now that NVMe disks can be accessed so fast, the CPU is approaching bottlnecking uncompressed transfers. Compression may hinder performance.

BTRFS Compression helps.

Spinning-Rust should be largely replaced by now with faster storage and limited to archival purposes.

Comment: In my experience, if you need any performance, avoid `btrfs`. It sure has nice features but performance is not one of those. If you need high performance on spinning rust, try ext4 or XFS instead. For example, see https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-50-filesystems

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here, but if you do prefer FS features over raw performance, use ZFS instead. It already saved my data once where btrfs couldn't have had, and it's not linux-specific. (EDIT: the "spinning rust" moniker is cute but evidently and inherently wrong.)